# How to use Netbeans with PHPUnit on Vagrant?

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, vagrant

I'm trying test my project using Netbeans (installed on Windows) and my server is located in a virtual machine (Virtualbox + Vagrant).

I saw this:
http://www.brianfenton.us/2012/03/running-phpunit-tests-on-vm-from.html#comment-form_4681337631658449555

But is not working and i got the error:
'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Here ismy config:

```
    :: remote serveur PuTTY silent connection (auto-login, key authentication with pageant)
set REMOTE_SERVER=vagrant@dev
:: root path of all local netbeans projects, despecialized for sed
set LOCAL_WORKSPACE=D:\/www
:: remote path of all projects, despecialized for sed
set REMOTE_WORKSPACE=\/var\/www
:: remote location of NetBeansSuite.php
set REMOTE_NETBEANSSUITE=\/usr\/local\/share\/php\/phpunit\/NetBeansSuite.php
```

... but i don't know what to do with:

```
set REMOTE_NETBEANSSUITE=\/usr\/local\/share\/php\/phpunit\/NetBeansSuite.php
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Not tested this on Windows yet, but I implemented a solution based on the blog post you mentioned, can be found here: [nb-remote-phpunit](https://github.com/stianlik/nb-remote-phpunit). It does not require sed, but you may need to modify the commands executing commands on your vagrant machine.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the "Stream EDitor" Unix command-line utility, and the comment with the batch file on that article you linked says you need to [install it on Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Sorry, I don't know why the batch file uses a test suite to run the test when the original shell script did not. :(

Comment: But I have installed the sed on windows.

Comment: Is it in your `%PATH%`?